# TableRow's single child doesn't stretch to match_parent

Tags: android, xml, android-tablelayout

My TableLayout contains TableRows that contain one child each.

TableLayout width is set to match_parent and works fine.

TableRow's width is automatically set to match_parent and that also works fine.

However, the child of the TableRow doesn't stretch to the whole width of the TableRow although is width is set to match_parent.

[image: TableRow's child not stressing to match_parent]

What am I missing?? Thanks

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:typefacetv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#772213" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/my_gray"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/LODGING_NAME" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_hotel_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borderless_white_5dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:text="@string/STARS" />

       <!--      <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_hotel_classtype"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borderless_white_5dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="5dp" /> -->
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/ADDRESS" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_hotel_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/borderless_white_5dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/PHONE" />

        <!--     <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/FAX" /> -->
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_hotel_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/borderless_white_5dp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:padding="5dp" />

        <!--     <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_hotel_fax"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/borderless_white_5dp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:padding="5dp" /> -->
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/EMAIL" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_hotel_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borderless_white_5dp"
                android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/WWW" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_hotel_website"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borderless_white_5dp"
                android:inputType="textUri"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save_hotel_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_typical_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/my_dark_gray"
    android:onClick="storeHotelInfo"
    android:text="@string/SAVE"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Please post whole xml. Are there any layout outer of ScrollView?

Comment: yes, there is an outer XML. Poste updated

Comment: Which child you are talking about ? Save button ?

Comment: no, I'm talking about the TextViews or EditTexts that belong to the TableRows. Such as the one highlighted in the image. It should stretch to the whole width.

Answer (score 5):

set your element's width to 0dp like android:layout_width="0dp" and use android:layout_weight="1" like below code

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_hotel_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text" />
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks. I was wondering if it's possible to do it without the use of weights.

Comment: No. The the view will always occupy that much space in table layout as much it required. If you want it to occupy the whole width then you will have to assign the weight.

Comment: it is not possible. One thing you can check that Is your TableLayout covering all your screen width or not, if not then use android:stretchColumns="*", may be this can do the trick .

Comment: both TableLayout and TableRow stretch to the full width, according to the "match_parent". It's only the child of the TableRow that doesn't respect the value...

Comment: do some R&D like change background color of TableLayout and TableRow and TextView. check which is not stretching to screen width. otherwise you use weights.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change the width of your all the views to `0dp` and assign the weight of `1` to each and add the height and width property of your each `TableRow` as below:

```
     <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_hotel_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/borderless_white_5dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </TableRow>
```

Do the same thing for all your rows.